# Image beside a paragraph bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello so I have a simple html code and this is the output:
[image]

While the code is

```
<img class="img-responsive" style="float:left;width:400px;height:700px;" src="../assets/images/san_jacinto.jpg">
<h3>Founding of the town</h3>
<p>Some text here/p>
```

Now I've managed to do it using [bootstrap 2.3.1 media](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.1/components.html#media) and now I got another problem:
[image]
What I need to fix now is the text should continue below the image. Is that possible in bootstrap also? Or if not, what else can I do?

Comment: Better use `padding-left` and `padding-right` properties  to the tags in css.

Answer (score 2):

you can use bootstrap [Media object](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#media) :

```
<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="media-object" src="..." alt="...">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @FewFlyBy yes, here is the link http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#media

Comment: Description from Bootstrap Media Object : The classes .pull-left and .pull-right also exist and were previously used as part of the media component, but are deprecated for that use as of v3.3.0. They are approximately equivalent to .media-left and .media-right, except that .media-right should be placed after the .media-body in the html.

Comment: Hi @Shehary thanks, now my problem is it did not continue at the end of the picture http://i.imgur.com/BcJ4U6w.png

Answer (score 0):

The solution is pleasingly easy, try placing your `P` and `h3` tags inside a parent `dive`,assign a **css** class to it, and add `paddings` to that **css** class. check it out here:

[padding](https://jsfiddle.net/mvLf2vxo/)

Comment: your solution works but it doesn't fully address what OP is asking in question

Comment: the OP has the false idea of adding margins to the element,s while the solution can be best attained using paddings...

Comment: do you even read the question? `is there a way in bootstrap to do this?`

Answer (score 0):

You can add some `right-margin` to image or 
`Left-padding` to paragraph or
`text-indent` to paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put the image inside a col-md-4 and the text inside col-md-8?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="../assets/images/san_jacinto.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <h3>Founding of the town</h3>
        <p>Some text here/p> 
    </div>
</div>
```